# preg_replace a link

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm wanting to use a preg_replace only to replace

```
"http://domain.com/dateiIe6EHOnzyl/_DSC7290.jpg.htm"
```

to

```
"http://domain.com/dateiIe6EHOnzyl.htm"
```

p/s: I need using only preg_replace

Comment: Where? In an HTML string, URL rewriting, what?

Comment: @DaveRandom, tag.. ehhm! btw, question upvoter, shame on you!

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good start to learn about regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$link = preg_replace('~/[^/]*(\.html?)$~', '$1', $link);
```

http://codepad.org/tVtZBD7L

Answer (score 0):

Try without preg_replace(), but with explode() and str_replace(), like in this example:

```
$str = 'http://domain.com/dateiIe6EHOnzyl/_DSC7290.jpg.htm';
$lastpart = end(explode('/', $str));
$str2 = str_replace('/'.$lastpart, '.htm', $str);
echo $str2;         // http://domain.com/dateiIe6EHOnzyl.htm
```

Comment: Thank,but i using only preg_replace

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'http://domain.com/dateiIe6EHOnzyl/_DSC7290.jpg.htm';
$str = preg_replace('/(.+)\/.+\.(.+)/','$1.$2',$str);
print $str;
```